# Java Fibonacci recursion code

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am trying to come up with a program to take from a user any number and produce the nth number for the fibonacci code. When I complete my work it's showing the next # instead of the # I need. For instance I'm looking for the 11th # and its producing 233 instead of 144. Here is my code:

```
public static int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n<=0)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n-2)+ fibonacci(n-1);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You Entered Number:" + number);
    System.out.println(number + "th Fibonacci Number is:"+ fibonacci(number));
    keyboard.close();        
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: fibonacci(0) = 0, not 1.

Comment: Your base case is wrong.  If n=0, return 0. If n=1, return 1.

Comment: change your first condition to return 0 and add an else if n==1 to return 1

Answer (score 5):

It's supposed to be

```
if(n == 0)
    return 0;
else if(n == 1)
    return 1;
else
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
```

because fibonacci(0) = 0

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an index.
You are printing the next Fibonacci number.
Change the

```
(n<=0)
```

to

```
(n<=1)
```

EDIT:

as the other answer says, fib(0) = 0, so you have to add this edge case too.

Comment: @M.Page It depends, sometimes we prefer a definition rather than the other. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 0):

Aleksandar already gave you the answer, still I think it is necessary to warn you that your code is extremely inefficient. Indeed, for computing `fibo(4)`, you are going to compute `fibo(3)` and `fibo(2)`. `fibo(3)` will require to compute `fibo(2)` and `fibo(1)` etc. Finally, you will take a lot of time computing already computed results (and you will use an exponential amount of memory for storing the local recursive calls context).

For a more efficient code, you ned to implement an iterative or a **tail-recursive** method. A tail-recursive method `meth` is a method which recursive calls are of the form `meth(f(args))`. In your case, your recursive call has the form `f(meth,args)` so it is not tail-recursive.

Here is a tail-recursive version :

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else 
        return fibonacciAux(0,1,n);
}

public static int fibonacciAux(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (count == 0)
        return b;
    else  
        return fibonacciAux(b,a + b,n - 1);
}
```

This version will run in linear time and will use a constant amount of memory, compared to a non-tail recursive version which will use an exponential time and memory.